# How do I bind/assign one PassthroughSubject to another?

Tags: swift, combine

I am coming from RxSwift and usually end up binding `PublishSubjects` together. I see that in `Combine` `PassthroughSubject` is the equivalent.

I have tried the following code:

```
let passthroughSubject1 = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
let passthroughSubject2 = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

private func bindEvents() {
    passthroughSubject1
        .assign(to: \.passthroughSubject1, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

However I get the error `Key path value type 'PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Void'`.

Is there not a way to bind two subjects together in `Combine`?

Comment: What does `binding` mean for you? What would you expect from such functionality?

Comment: Like an RxSwift binding. eg `passthroughSubject1.bind(to: passthroughSubject2)` so when `passthroughSubject1` is triggered it will pass the event along to `passthroughSubject2`. More elegant than using sink `{ [weak self] _ in self?. passthroughSubject2.(()) }`

Comment: OK, but I still fail to see what's your exact need. Why do you need this "binding" functionality? Can you update the question and add a concrete usage example?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing up different things.

The `assign` operator is used to **set** variables. In your example you are trying to set `passthroughSubject1` of type `PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>` to type `Void`.

So *this* would work:

```
var passthroughSubject1 = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>() //changed Void to String
var variable1: String = ""
var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()

passthroughSubject1.assign(to: \.variable1, on: self)
  .store(in: &store)
```

I do not know what you mean with:

> end up binding PublishSubjects together

but if you want to chain them (emitting with `passthroughSubject2` when `passthroughSubject1` is emitting a value) you would use a sink.

```
var passthroughSubject1 = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()
var passthroughSubject2 = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()

passthroughSubject1.sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] in
    self?.passthroughSubject2.send()
}).store(in: &store)
```

If you want to react when one of the two publishers emits a value you can use the `Publishers.CombineLatest` function:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest(passthroughSubject1, passthroughSubject2)
    .sink(receiveValue: {_,_ in
        // one of the two publishers emitted a value
    }).store(in: &store)
```

[documentation for assign(to:on:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:on:))